# IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to add and delete new items to RecyclerView - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a To Do List program using RecyclerView on Android Studio. Basically it just has to add new tasks when add button is clicked and delete checked tasks when delete button is clicked. First addition and deletions work fine, but after a while it starts to act strange and eventually crash, giving me an IndexOutOfBounds exception when trying to add, delete or check a checkbox.

Here is my code:
Adapter:

```
package com.example.todolistapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TodolistRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodolistRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ToDo> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public TodolistRecViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todolist_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.taskToDo.setText(tasks.get(position).getTask());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(tasks.get(position).isChecked());

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                tasks.get(position).setChecked(!tasks.get(position).isChecked());

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }

    public void setTasks(ArrayList<ToDo> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addTask(ToDo task) {
        tasks.add(task);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteTasks() {

        int totalsize = tasks.size();
        for(int i=tasks.size() -1; i>=0; --i) {
            if(tasks.get(i).isChecked())
            {
                tasks.remove(i);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView taskToDo;
        private CheckBox checkbox;
        private ConstraintLayout parent;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            taskToDo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskToBeDoneTxt);
            parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            checkbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.todolistapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TodolistRecViewAdapter adapter;

    private ConstraintLayout parent;
    private Button addBtn;
    private EditText editText;
    private String toDoTask;
    private Button deleteBtn;

    private RecyclerView todolistRecView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        deleteBtn = findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

        todolistRecView = findViewById(R.id.todolistRecView);

        ArrayList<ToDo> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        ToDo taskToDo = new ToDo("Atalay");

        tasks.add(taskToDo);

        adapter = new TodolistRecViewAdapter(this);

        adapter.setTasks(tasks);

        todolistRecView.setAdapter(adapter);
        todolistRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ToDo newtask = new ToDo(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.addTask(newtask);
            }
        });

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.deleteTasks();
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

ToDo Class:

```
package com.example.todolistapp;

public class ToDo {
    String task;
    boolean checked;

    public ToDo(String task) {
        this.task = task;
        this.checked = false;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Exception message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.todolistapp, PID: 27013
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.todolistapp.TodolistRecViewAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(TodolistRecViewAdapter.java:44)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:218)
        at com.example.todolistapp.TodolistRecViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TodolistRecViewAdapter.java:39)
        at com.example.todolistapp.TodolistRecViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TodolistRecViewAdapter.java:19)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27013 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you post the entire exception message? That will help us determine the line of code to start debugging.

Comment: I added the exception message too. Problem is at 44th line in Adapter class. tasks.get(position).setChecked(!tasks.get(position).isChecked()); .

Comment: It's weird indeed. However, try to do something else: instead of getting the object from the list in every call, create a local variable inside the onBindViewHolder method which gets the item from the list. Then, replace all tasks.get(position) for the new variable. This will ensure that the OOB exception does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do this:
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
before line:
holder.checkbox.setChecked(tasks.get(position).isChecked());
I don't know if you aware of this, but RecyclerView is reusing views. What means - when you are adding new task and RecyclerView is creating new view for that cell it works fine. I suspect that when you deleted some views and are trying to add new once sometimes RecyclerView decides to reuse the View, which was binded before to other data. In that case , when you setChecked() in the bindVieHolder() method the old listener is called and is trying to find item, which was deleted already and you want to replace it.
So this is just about clearing the listener.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although I still don't fully understand how it solved the problem.

Comment: It is simple. Read more about RecyclerView reusings cells. You will understand what happend.